# Android Callback failure does not work

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, callback

I want to know how to prevent the android application from crushing while an execution error happens.

I'm using this project [here](https://github.com/DynamicsCRM/Android-Activity-Tracker-for-Dynamics-CRM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/activitytracker/Activities/MainActivity.java).

the error occurs when the requests does not find any result or when it takes to much time.

```
 FetchExpression fetchExpression = new FetchExpression(
                Utils.getEscapedContactSearchTermFetch(query));
        mOrgService.RetrieveMultiple(fetchExpression, new Callback<EntityCollection>() {
            @Override
            public void success(EntityCollection entityCollection) {
                mMainList.setAdapter(new SearchResultsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), entityCollection));
                mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(Throwable error) {
                displayError(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

the method failure does not work in some cases.

How can I prevent this application from crushing.

Thanks,

Comment: in the cases the failure does not work, what exception do you get?

Comment: I get no exception, the application crushs only

Comment: if you connect he device to a computer with Android Studio, when the app crashes you can see the stack trace in the android console tab, look for the exception there.

Answer (score 0):

You should put that block of code in a try catch block and add the error you want to get in the catch block.

```
try {
    some code here
    ....
} catch(Exception yourException) {
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem I beleive that it may has some limits because I'm trying to send many requests and in this case some times the application crushs but with no errors, Even with the try catch it does not catch any error it just crushs

Comment: What's the timeout duration?

Comment: less than 10 seconds I guess

Comment: You'll have to throw a timeout exception and increase the timeout